# Unable to access the fields of Firebase Firestore doc in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to Access the field of document and for that i am using the following code but I am getting the error:-

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (Documentation)
```

My cloud firestore version is `cloud_firestore: ^2.1.0`

**My code:-**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class TeamModel
{
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String url;
  final String category;
  final String role;

  TeamModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.url,
    this.category,
    this.role
  });

  factory TeamModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc)
  {
    return TeamModel(
      id: doc.id,
      name: doc.data()['name'],// I am getting the error on this ['name']
      url: doc.data()['url'], // same error here
      category: doc.data()['category'],// same error here
      role: doc.data()['role'],// same error here
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead without `.data()`

```
factory TeamModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc)
  {
    return TeamModel(
      id: doc.id,
      name: doc['name'],
      url: doc['url'],
      category: doc['category'],
      role: doc['role'],
    );
  }
```