# How to specify field for snapshot data in firebase-flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, snapshot

from the previous question that I have [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67329011/send-notification-over-device-using-fcm-and-flutter), I already managed to send a push notification to all device. Previously, I am using the different version of plugin which are:

```
firebase_core: ^1.0.1
cloud_firestore: ^1.0.1
firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.8.0
```

But, there are some issue on compatibility for my firebase connection as I need to change from

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

to

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

So, due to compatibility issue, i need to change the version of plugin as well to

```
firebase_core: ^1.2.0
cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0
```

However, after change the version. Some of my code didn't work. My concern is on how to specify which field that I want to call using `snapshot.data()`. Previously, I am using `snapshot.data()['token']` and it's work fine. But after I change version on `firebase_core`, I cannot using that method again. It stated error which is:

> Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
>
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'. Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
>   'to': snapshot.data() ['tokenID'],

Can anyone help me on this issue? Thank you in advanced! You many check the full code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67329011/send-notification-over-device-using-fcm-and-flutter)

Comment: See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67565026/13840864

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `snapshot.data()` to a Map like shown below:

```dart
    (snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>) ['tokenID']
```

Checkout the [migration guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/#migration) for cloud_firestore 2.0.0.

> With the release of withConverter, numerous classes/functions take an
> extra generic parameter. In most cases, type inference should take
> care of the migration for you. But in some cases, you may have to
> specify that generic parameter yourself.